# Formatting CSS into single or multiple lines based on property count

Tags: css, regex, notepad++, code-formatting

Consider the following CSS:

```
.foo {
 color: red;
}

.bar {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.baz { color: pink }
```

*My singular problem is:* What regex would format that code as follows - All declarations with one property (.foo) should be on *one line*. Any declarations with more than one property (.bar) should remain on multiple lines. One declaration rules that already happen to be on one line (.baz) should remain as such.

```
.foo { color: red }

.bar {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.baz { color: pink }
```

I have tried with Notepad++ as an obvious, and powerful choice, but the exact regex eludes me.

**What I specifically tried:**

I tried a search replace using wildcards:

Search:

```
{*\r\n}
```

Replace:

```
{ $1 }
```

Comment: A close and down vote. You couldn't make it up. If it wasn't for the likes of the two people below that took their time, and applied their expertise to help, I'd abandon this site in a heartbeat. One thing I don't understand, is that if a question is worth a (really great) answer, shouldn't the question itself get an upvote? Doesn't the effort of the answer imply it was a good question?

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way. Across Stack Overflow and egregiously in the regex tag specifically you should show what you've attempted. It doesn't matter if it's completely wrong or just 1 character shy of right, it gives us hints as to which concepts you already understand and also provides insights into expected edge-cases. As it stands your question boils down to "do this for me". I thought your question was an interesting challenge for myself personally so I did provide an answer; I did not downvote nor supply the close vote.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - I appreciate the clarification. In fairness I did offer a very rough outline of what I'd thought about. I'll try editing the question, although how... I do not know.

Comment: I've edited your question to just the necessities. The contributors which are any good on this site don't care for puffery. Just make it easy to identify your problem, goal, and present your attempt. Stack Overflow is a fickle beast...

Comment: OK. It felt good to shout mostly into the void for a second :) Take care.

Comment: No worries, good luck. I do appreciate that you are actually a contributor with a few hundred answers under your belt. Far too many people show up and feel entitled to an answer just because their problem is important to them. Addtionally, "Interestingly, any questions I ever have where I can show you "what I've done". **I tend to solve myself**." - yes, that's the point =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, even for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

**regex**

```regex
{\s*+([^:{}]+:[^:{}]+?)\s*}
```

- `{\s*+` - detect opening curly brace and greedily capture whitespace
- `([^:{}]+:[^:{}]+?)` - find one property and save it into capture group 1
- `\s*+}` - greedily capture whitespaces and a closing curly brace

**replace**

```
{ $1 }
```

- Format the output into the desired newline-less style

https://regex101.com/r/j5NPQH/1

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked straight out of the box. Bonus kudos for considering media queries. In fact I used this on SCSS, with all sorts of other edge cases (includes, variables, mixins) and it compiled afterwards perfectly. Thanks again mate, much appreciated.

Comment: @mayersdesign I'm glad you like it! One edge case which I  also coded against is having a property and value on a newline. So `color: {newline} blue` would also be handled if it is present in your source text.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `{\s+(.+)\s+}`
- Replace with: `{ $1 }`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
{           # literally
\s+         # 1 or more spaces
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
\s+         # 1 or more spaces
}           # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I am sure this works as well as the answer above that just beat you to the post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mayersdesign: You're welcome, glad it helps.